How to edit the php/html/css code created by the a plugin in wordpress using cpanel
I want to edit the HTML of an element in Elementor (add a title or entry in it). Based on my understanding, the files for these elements can be accessed using the cpanel file navigator. How do I find the specific files for these elements and modify them?

Hi, not sure exactly what you want to modify, but you should not modify any plugins files, any update there will be gone with plugins updates, same goes for themes. Any modifications should be done in your child theme or own custom plugin. You should extend functionalities form other plugins and themes using actions and filters hooks and templates overrides if available. However if you still want to take a look at files, plugins and themes are located under wp-content/themes or wp-content/plugins

Thanks for the help. I guess I will have to find some other way to modify the elements.

You can share more details of what you want to accomplish, maybe there is another way.
